# How to avoid hover styles when using only-child

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am using the only-child selector to show a specific background color, and a hover style to show a different background color. The problem is that I do not want the hover style to work when there is only one child. How can I do that?

1) No red background, but it changes to a green background when we hover

```css
.report p:only-child {
  background: red;
}

.report p:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="report">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test2</p>
</div>
```

2) Red background, but no green background when we hover

```css
.report p:only-child {
  background: red;
}

.report p:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="report">
  <p>Test1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your selector to additionally use the not selector as below

```
.report p:not(:only-child):hover{
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I am selecting this answer as it came earlier

Answer (score 5):

Easy, just combine those two pseudo-classes you already have :)

```
.report p:only-child,
.report p:only-child:hover{
    background: red;
}
.report p:hover{
    background: green;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ccjphjj/

Answer (score 1):

Try `.report p:not(:only-child):hover`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.report p:only-child {
  background: red;
}

.report p:not(:only-child):hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="report">
  <p>Test1</p>
</div>

<div class="report">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the reason is probably because your answer is an exact copy of an existing, older answer